# How to solve deep learning error concatenate layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, generative-adversarial-network

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "tf.concat_19" (type TFOpLambda)
My image shape is (64,64,3) These are downsampling and upsampling function I made for generator & discriminator for my CycleGAN.

```
def downsample(filters, kernel_size, apply_instance_norm=True, n_strides=2) :
  model = tf.keras.Sequential()
  model.add(Conv2DTranspose(filters, kernel_size, strides = n_strides, padding = 'same',
             kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(0.,0.02), use_bias = False))
  if apply_instance_norm :
    model.add(tfa.layers.InstanceNormalization())
  model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
  return model

def upsample(filters, kernel_size) :
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      Conv2DTranspose(filters, kernel_size, strides=2, padding = 'same',
             kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(0.,0.02), use_bias = False),
      tfa.layers.InstanceNormalization(),
      LeakyReLU(0.2),
  ])
  
  return model
```

The generator model :

```
def generator() :
  input = Input((IM_SHAPE[0], IM_SHAPE[1], 3))
  x = input
  store = []
  for filter in [32,64,128,256,512,] :
    x = downsample(filter, 4)(x)
    store.append(x)
  for filter in [512,256,128,64,3] :
    x = tf.concat([x, store.pop()], axis = -1)
    x = upsample(filter, 4)(x)
  model = tf.keras.Model(input, x, name='unet_generator')
  return model
```

The discriminator encountered no problem when I checked its summary(). But when I tried to check generator().summary(), I got this Error :

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "tf.concat_19" (type TFOpLambda).

Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 4096 and 1024. Shapes are [?,4096,4096] and [?,1024,1024]. for '{{node tf.concat_19/concat}} = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32](Placeholder, Placeholder_1, tf.concat_19/concat/axis)' with input shapes: [?,4096,4096,512], [?,1024,1024,256], [] and with computed input tensors: input[2] = <-1>.

Call arguments received by layer "tf.concat_19" (type TFOpLambda):
  • values=['tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 4096, 4096, 512), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1024, 1024, 256), dtype=float32)']
  • axis=-1
  • name=concat
```